# Estimating the minimum of a finite probability mass function

Tags: probability, extreme-value

Suppose we are given a discrete r.v. $X$, distributed according to some *unknown*, finite probability mass function $p(x)$. We can assume that $p(x)>0$ for every $x$ in its domain. We can sample $X$ i.i.d. and obtain a sample

$S= (X_1,...,X_m)$.

Problem: how can we *formally* lower-bound $p_*=\min_x p(x)$, within a certain confidence?
To be more specific, I'd like an estimator $\hat p_*(S)$ for which it is possible to prove something like this, for any $1\geq \lambda\geq 0$:

$\Pr(|p_*- \hat p_*(S)|>\lambda)\leq f(\lambda,m)$

for some rapidly decreasing function $f$ of $\lambda$ and $m$. For example, $f(\lambda,m)=\exp(-c\lambda^2m)$, for some constant $c>0$.

Any reference to the relevant literature would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: NB: just to avoid any confusion about the terminology, by "distribution" $p(x)$ I mean $\Pr(X=x)=p(x)$ (this is sometimes worded as "density"...).

Comment: If $X$ is *discrete* (that was an important change), you don't call $p(x) = P(X=x)$ a density; it's usually called either a probability function or probability mass function.

Comment: Do you really mean to write a *two-sided* formula for $p_{*}$? Normally, a "lower bound" would be a value $\tau$ for which $\Pr(\hat{p}_{*}(S)\le\tau)$ is guaranteed to be sufficiently small.

Comment: Changed again. Note that I declared $p$ to be finite from the beginning. Anyway, I hope it is clear what I mean: $\Pr(X=x)=p(x)$ for each $x$ in the sample space of $X$.

Comment: @whuber: as you put it, what would be the relation between $\hat{p}_{*}(S)$ and $p_{*}$?

Comment: $\tau$ is a lower bound for $p_{*}$. Alternatively, you could seek a relation of the following form: if $p_{*}\lt\lambda(\tau,\epsilon),$ then $\Pr(\hat{p}_{*}\gt\tau)\lt \epsilon.$ Here, $\lambda(\tau,\epsilon)$ is a (probabilistic) lower bound for $p_{*}$, $\epsilon$ is taken to be small, and the interpretation is that when the estimator exceeds $\tau,$ it is unlikely $p_{*}$ is any smaller than $\lambda$.

Comment: @user35573 while you certainly 'declared p to be finite' it was not clear in the original what, exactly, you were saying was finite - when you used the word 'density' I assumed you meant that the density was bounded. Presumably you intend that the sample space of $X$ is finite, not $p$ itself - which must be finite, since it's now clearly a probability (always between 0 and 1)

Comment: I really meant the *domain* of $p$, as a (probability mass) function, was finite. Apologies for having been so sloppy.

Comment: Is the support of the finite distribution known? Let's say it's $\{x_1,\dots,x_k\}$, for known real numbers $x_i$.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for are called concentration bounds in statistical learning theory. [Here](http://www.econ.upf.edu/~lugosi/anu.pdf) is a good primer by Gabor Lugosi.

You can find more relevant literature from course websites for learning theory.

Comment: Many thanks.  I know about concentration bounds (method of bounded differences and the like). But this particular bound seems particularly awkward to tackle using those techniques. For example, I have no problem to prove concentration bounds for the maximum of $p(x)$. Thanks for the pointer, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common schema. The exact form you have mentioned is used in most standard methods to prove bounds in randomized algorithms. The logic is as follows: Suppose my task is X. I develop a randomized scheme and show using the bounds you have mentioned that P(X not happens) approaches zero.

The key steps in these proofs involves using the Markov or Chebyshev inequality which has the form you want. Some ingenuity goes in figuring out how to chose the correct p* and how to reduce the right hand side to the form you require

Answer (score 0):

Here are some easy calculations that you might have considered, but still seem worth jotting down.  (Disclaimer: I am not an expert and think there are better solutions).

For convenience, suppose the state space is $\{0,1,\ldots,N\}$, and $p_0 < p_1 \le p_x$ for $x = 1, \ldots, N$.  So $0$ is the (strictly) least likely outcome and $p_* = p_0$ in this case.  (For now assume that $N$ is known.)

Take the i.i.d. sample $X_1, \ldots, X_m \sim (p_x)$.

Let $L$ denote the outcome that occurs least often, i.e. $L$ is such that $\#\{i:X_i = L\}$ is minimal (with ties broken arbitrarily).  A first step is to show $L = 0$ has a good probability.

Define $c = (p_1 - p_0)/2 > 0$ by assumption.  Note that $p_0 + c = p_1 - c = (p_0 + p_1)/2$.

If $\#\{i:X_i = 0\} < m(p_0 + c)$ and $\#\{i:X_i = x\} > m(p_1 -c)$ for all $x$ then $L = 0$.  Hence $L \neq 0$ implies one of these inequalities does not hold.  Observe that $\#\{i:X_i = x\}$ has Binomial$(m,p_x)$ distribution, for every $x$.  Thus, Hoeffding's inequality gives
$$
P( \#\{i:X_i = 0\} \ge n(p_0 + c) ) \le e^{-2m c^2},
$$
and 
$$
P( \#\{i:X_i = x\} \le n(p_1 + c) ) \le P( \#\{i:X_i = x\} \le n(p_x + c) )
\le e^{-2m c^2}.
$$

Union bounding thus gives
$$
P(L \neq 0) \le (N+1)e^{-2m c^2}.
$$

The obvious estimator to use now is $\hat p_* = \#\{i:X_i = L\}/m$, the smallest observed fraction.

We get

\begin{align}
P(|\hat p_* - p_*| \ge a) 
& = P(|\hat p_* - p_*| \ge a, L=0) +  
P(|\hat p_* - p_*| \ge a, L=0) + P(|\hat p_* - p_*| \ge a, L\ne 0) \\
& \le P(|\hat p_* - p_*| \ge a, L=0) + (N+1)e^{-2m c^2} \\
& \le P(|\#\{i:X_i = 0\}/m - p_*| \ge a)  +(N+1)e^{-2m c^2} \\
& \le 2 e^{-2m a^2} + (N+1)e^{-2m c^2}.
\end{align}

So, if you have some idea of the state space size $N$, and also the difference $p_1 - p_0$ for how less likely the least likely outcome is, then you're in business.

I will expand this post later with some thoughts about estimating $N$ and $p_1 - p_0$, which actually seems to be the tough part of the problem!